# How to Save Item of The Indexed Array That Had Been Changed Into String Into Variable Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, sorting, string-concatenation

May I ask my first question. Sorry if the title is so bad. It was a bit annoy me. So I was build a function to reverse a string that have 5 character or more like this.

```
function spinWords(str) {
    str2 = str.split(" ");
    str3 = [];
      
    for (i = 0; i < str2.length; i++) {
       str3 = str2[i].split("");
       if (str3.length >= 5) {
          str3.reverse();
       }
       str4 = str3.join("");
       return str4;
    }
}
spinWords("Welcome To The Club");`
```

The output that I expected is like this

```
emocleW To The Club
```

But that code output is this

```
emocleW
To
The
Club
```

Is there any solution, at least to combine the four iteration string into one line?

Every help would be very nice. Thanks!!!

Comment: Your expected behavior does not make sense. Will you check again?

Comment: Thanks, for answer it, yeah, i really new here, i don't understand how to write code in here. And i realized that the printed code is not what i expected
Here the code

function spinWords(str) {
  str2 = str.split(" ");
  str3 = [];
  for (i = 0; i < str2.length; i++) {
    str3 = str2[i].split("");

    if (str3.length >= 5) {
      str3.reverse();
    }

    str4 = str3.join("");
    return str4;
  }

}

spinWords("Welcome");

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
function spinWords(str) {

  function reverseString(str) {
    return str.split("").reverse().join(""); 
  }

  const words = str.split(" ");
  const spinnedWords = words.map(word => {
    if (word.length >=5 ) return reverseString(word);
    else return word;
  });

  return spinnedWords.join(' ');
}

spinWords("Welcome To The Club");
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems you are printing the array which would give that result, you would need to join the array to get it on one line like so

```
myArray.join(" ");
```

A short example that would do the thing you want

```
function spinWords(str) {
 return str.split(" ")
   .map((word) => word.length > 4 
     ? word.split('').reverse().join('') // Reverses a string
     : word
   )
   .join(" ");
}
```